# Unramified extension of $ \Bbb{Z}_p$ and $ \Bbb{Z}_p$ itself is isom as a ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Unramified extension of $ \Bbb{Z}_p$ is isom as a ring ?

Let $L/ \Bbb{Q}_p$ be unramified extension, and $o$ be $L$'s ring of integers.
We call $o$ be the unramified extension of $ \Bbb{Z}_p$.

Does $ \Bbb{Z}_p$ and $o$ is isom as ring ?

This does not match my intuition, but I heard this holds in general.
If this holds, I want to know the reason why.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that if $\mathbb{Z}_p\simeq o$ then you have an isomorphism of fraction fields $\mathbb{Q}_p\simeq L$. Hence the rings are not isomorphic except in the trivial case.

It is true that $p$ generates the maximal ideal of $o$, however.

Comment: Here’s another way to put it: $o$ and $\mathbb{Z}_p$ can’t be isomorphic as rings, because $\mathbb{Z}_p$ contains only the $(p-1)$-th roots of unity, while $o$ contains all the $(q-1)$-th roots of unity, where $q=p^{[L:\mathbb{Q}_p]}$.

Comment: @Mindlack that is incorrect when $p = 2$: the roots of unity in $\mathbf Z_2$ are $\pm 1$, not just $1$.